Proper syntax for a function that takes two functions with variable parameters?
I have a lot of async calls in my application. They retrieve data from a server and execute a callback with the retrieved data. I want to handle them them following way:

Execute function with reference parameters. This function reaches out to the database, parses data, and sets the out-parameters.
Execute callback. This function takes in the out parameters of the previous function. It is executed when the previous function is done.

This is my current approach:
template<typename... T>
void exec_async(std::function<void(T&...)> func, std::function<void(T&...)> callback, T... args)
{
    std::future<void> result = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
    {
        func(args...);
        callback(args...);
    });
}


void callback_func(const std::string& output)
{
    std::cout << "Output: " << output << std::endl;
}

void exec_func()
{
    auto func = [](std::string& in)
    {
        in = "testing";
    };

    exec_async<std::string>(func, &callback_func, "");
}

This approach works fine, but to use it I have to pass in a default set of variables after func and callback. Ideally I would not have to do this. How can I use this approach but not have to specify default variables?
i.e exec_async<std::string>(func, &callback_func); instead of exec_async<std::string>(func, &callback_func, "");
Ideally I would initialize the variables in exec_async, pass them into func, then into callback. Something like this:
template<typename... T>
void exec_async(std::function<void(T&...)> func, std::function<void(T&...)> callback)
{
    T ...args;
    std::future<void> result = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
    {
        func(args...);
        callback(args...);
    });
}

But I cannot get anything like this to compile. What is the correct approach to this?

Here is the correct implementation:
template<typename... T>
std::future<void> exec_async(std::function<void(T&...)> func, std::function<void(const T&...)> callback)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [func, callback]
    {
        std::tuple<T...> args{};
        std::apply(func, args);
        std::apply(callback, args);
    });
}


Admittedly courtesy of ChatGPT. I would not have bothered trying this.
Explanation for why this works (courtesy of me):
std::tuple can store many variables with different types. T... args is not a valid parameter pack if declared within a function. T... is, however, perfectly acceptable by templates. Here, a tuple is created with all the required arguments. std::tuple is default initialized, so I do not need to worry about that. std::apply calls the provided function with the tuple converted into a parameter list.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

@StephenNewell I am aware of the generative AI ban, but since I am actively using this code and I can verify it with my own knowledge of how these functions work and I provided a self-written explanation of the code from my own knowledge (as Stack Overflow requires) I think this should be fine. I can remove the attribution if necessary.

@Eshy indeed in this case the atribution is unnecessary IMHO. The verified solution with a a self-written explanation  is all that is needed and it does not matter in which way you got to it.

the meta article is rather clear about "All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow."

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I understand and agree with the rational regarding the generative AI ban. No doubt it produces a lot of unreliable (not to say garbage) answers. And the meta article indeed mentions this problem. But it this case it seems like the asnwerer did not rely on the AI answer, but rather validated it properly and came up with a self written explanation. They could have ommitted the whole mention of the generative AI. So I thought that in this case it is OK and does contribute to the quality of content here. Can you explain why am I wrong ?

@wohlstad Imho proper attribution and making it clear waht the own work is would be ok. But where is the line? Who defines where that line is? Who decides each single case? The Temporary policy answers all that.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I see your point. Fair enough.
